# Call another rest api with payload from my server in Spring-Boot kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, post

I want to call another web-api from my server with payload using post method,
For example,

https://api.example.com.bd/subscription/query-base

Payload :

Content type
application/json;charset=utf-8

```
{

    "applicationId": "APP_000201",
    "password": "39a8d1cb245029d0560619a2b388669c"

}
```

Response samples :

```
{
  "baseSize": "0",
  "version": "1.0.",
  "statusCode": "S1000",
  "statusDetail": "Success."
}
```

I want to return only baseSize that method how to do it

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about making a request to a REST API. The way to do this in Spring is to use `RestTemplate`. You will typically want to define a bean to inject the rest template into whatever class you want to make the call from. You will likely be using one of the following methods to call your API: `exchange`, `postForObject`, or `postForEntity`.

I would recommend reading some documentation on how to use the RestTemplate before going further. [Here is a good starting point.](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) The code is in Java, but the basic idea is the same in Kotlin.